# Synchronized on a monitor

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm just trying to further my understanding of this concept.

We have a monitor, let's say a queue or a map of some sort. This monitor has methods to put objects on, and get objects off. In order to be thread safe, the monitor will lock on it's put methods and on it's get methods. When a thread is synchronized to this monitor, it's constantly trying to obtain this monitor's right's so it can proceed with what it needs to do. Does this sound right?

Another question, how does the flow of control work here. Which code is executed once the thread has gained access to the monitor? I'm finding it hard to debug multi-threaded programs with just print statements, it get's really messy and confusing.

```
public void run(){
    try{
        synchronized (monitor){
            while (monitor is empty){
                 monitor.wait(); // Does this line pause the thread or the monitor?
            }

            System.out.println("Done Waiting");
        }
        System.out.println("Out of the synchronized block");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't think of it like that at all. A monitor doesn't have methods or fields or anything. A monitor is not something _you_ can interact with. You interact with objects. Objects have monitors.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the definition from the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1):

> The Java programming language provides multiple mechanisms for
>   communicating between threads. The most basic of these methods is
>   synchronization, which is implemented using monitors. **Each object in
>   Java is associated with a monitor**, which a thread can lock or unlock.
>   **Only one thread at a time may hold a lock on a monitor. Any other
>   threads attempting to lock that monitor are blocked until they can
>   obtain a lock on that monitor.** A thread t may lock a particular
>   monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock
>   operation.

To answer

> This monitor has methods to put objects on, and get objects off. In
>   order to be thread safe, the monitor will lock on it's put methods and
>   on it's get methods. When a thread is synchronized to this monitor,
>   it's constantly trying to obtain this monitor's right's so it can
>   proceed with what it needs to do. Does this sound right?

So you're not interacting with a monitor. A monitor doesn't have a concept of methods. Don't think of it like that. You interact with objects which have monitors. When a thread acquires an object's monitor, it doesn't need to constantly trying to obtain it, **it already has it**.

> Another question, how does the flow of control work here. Which code
>   is executed once the thread has gained access to the monitor? I'm
>   finding it hard to debug multi-threaded programs with just print
>   statements, it get's really messy and confusing.

If execution enters the `synchronized` block on an object, the currently executing thread has acquired the monitor on the `synchronized` object, in this case the object referenced by the variable `monitor`.

I'll assume (thanks to Radiodeaf) that by `monitor is empty`, you mean your `Map` object doesn't have any entries.

When you call

```
monitor.wait();
```

the current thread releases the monitor on the object referenced by `monitor` and sleeps until it gets notified.

The javadoc of [`Object#wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) has more details.

So you will loop on the check for empty and wait if it returns `true`. We can assume that some other piece of code calls `notify()` when they put something into the `Map`.

When the object does get notified, the thread then has to compete to re-acquire the object's monitor. This is obviously necessary so that the thread can be executing inside a `synchronized` block on the object.

Comment: *"I don't know what you mean by monitor is empty"* The OP's monitor object is a Map. (It's in their other question.)

Answer (score 0):

As we know We can call wait method only from synchronized context.
So By saying wait release the lock we mean that once lock is acquired on an object when it is in synchronized context , by calling wait method on same object , it release the lock and allow other thread to work on that object.